# Optimizing Apps: Why?

Tags: reboot, optimization

I have a Kyocera Hydro View. Every time I restart my phone, it tells me that Android is optimizing apps. This takes anywhere from 5 to 15 minutes, and sometimes prevents me from using the phone when I need to use it.

What is Android doing, and why does it need to do it so often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something in Android that is called the dalvik-cache.  It's basically an optimized version of the android package you usually install/download on your phone. This is usually done while installation and doesn't need to happen at every boot. However,  in your case,  reboots apparently trigger a dalvik-cache dump(for lack of a better word). So,  Android has to optimize all apps all over again. 
I'd suggest you to try and diagnose why your phone is clearing it's dalvik-cache at every boot. Are you running a custom ROM?

Comment: It's been going on for the past month or two.

Comment: Try to recall as to what triggered it. Usually OTA updates trigger a dalvik-cache dump.

Comment: I have not had any OTA updates, nor am I able to purposely trigger it. Also, I'm on Lollipop. Isn't Dalvik replaced with something else?

Comment: Yes. It's called ART.  However, the cache is still called dalvik-cache.